# If $A\geq B$ and $A>C$, then does it follow that $B>C$?

Tags: inequality, arithmetic

If $A\geq B$ and $A>C$, then does it follow that $B>C$?

I'm trying to prove some inequalities about the inf and sup of the range of functions, and this scenario came up.

Ok so the question is prove $\inf\{f(x)+g(x)\}<=\inf\{f(x)\}+\sup\{g(x)\}$

Comment: Let $B=A-3,C=A-2$

Comment: Take $B = C$...

Comment: Just post your "inequalities about the inf and sup of the range of functions"

Comment: The OP has edited the question so much that the (previously correct) answer no longer applies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Consider $A = 1$, $B = -1$ and $C = 0$.

In general, if $A > B$ and $A > C$, then you can't say whether $B > C$, $B = C$, or $B < C$. Likewise, if $A < B$ and $A < C$, you can't compare $B$ and $C$.

If $A > B$ and $B > C$, then $A > C$. Likewise, if $A < B$ and $B < C$, then $A < C$. That is, $<$ and $>$ are transitive.

---

I'm assuming you want to show

$$\inf\{f(x) + g(x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\} \leq \inf\{f(x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\} + \sup\{g(x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$ Let $c = \sup \{g(x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Note that $f(x) + g(x) \leq f(x) + c$. Now use the fact that $\inf(A + b) = \inf A + b$ where $b \in \mathbb{R}$ is fixed and $A + b = \{a + b \mid a \in A\}$.